# Show with DCT: $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{id\theta}{\sqrt{1+R^{-2}e^{-2i\theta}}}=\int_0^{2\pi} id\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $R \in \mathbb C$. Is it possible to show
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{id\theta}{\sqrt{1+R^{-2}e^{-2i\theta}}}=\int_0^{2\pi} id\theta
$$
using the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: What do you call $\sqrt{1+R^{-2}\mathrm e^{-2i\theta}}$?

Comment: @did This is the radius of the complex number $1+iR^{-1}e^{-i\theta}$.

Comment: @did So $\|1+iR^{-1}e{-i\theta}\|^2=1+R^{-2}e^{-2i\theta} \ge 1$, and DCT follows. Is it correct?

Comment: No, the radius of the complex number $1+iR^{-1}e^{-i\theta}$ is $\sqrt{1+|R|^{-2}-2\Im(e^{-i\theta}R^{-1})}$.

Comment: @did I see your point. How do I get a lower bound for this radius?

Comment: This is $\geqslant\sqrt{1+|R|^{-2}-2|R|^{-1}}=1-|R|^{-1}$ if $|R|\geqslant1$.

Comment: @did We showed $\sqrt{1+|R|^{-2}-2\Im(R^{-1}e^{-i\theta})} \ge 1-|R|^{-1}$.
But I need a lower bound for $\sqrt{1+R^{-2}e^{-2i\theta}}$ to apply the DCT. What is the link between these?

Comment: Once again, $\sqrt{1+R^{-2}e^{-2i\theta}}$ has no (canonical) definition. The modulus of $1+iR^{-1}e^{-i\theta}$ is given by the formula I wrote, **not by** $\sqrt{1+R^{-2}e^{-2i\theta}}$, **which has no meaning**. And the best uniform lower bound for the modulus of $1+iR^{-1}e^{-i\theta}$ **is the one I gave you**. (Believe it or not, my comments are not composed randomly...)

Comment: @did I believe you are pretty strong, finding this lower bound on the spot. Any idea for the original question?

Comment: The modulus is between $1-|R|^{-1}$ and $1+|R|^{-1}$, uniformly on $\theta$ hence yes, the limit of the integral exists and it is $2\pi i$.